# Cognito Authorizer testing failed with access token

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-api-gateway

I created `Cognito Authorizer` with API Gatwway and need to test. If I used the `access` token with Cognito Authorzer, it is failing. But If I called the api gateway with the `access` token, it works. I want to test the `Cognito Authorizer` it self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you test `Cognito Authorizer` itself, then you have to use `ID token`, not the `Access token` . I faced the same issue and took ages to figure out.

This video could be helpful as it shows step by step "Secure API Gateway using Cognito" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9crTLAT_4uY